# How do it create a Visual Studio 2015 Package, and - where the heck is the SDK?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-sdk, visual-studio-package

Trying to create a "Visual Studio Package" (a tool for use by developers within Visual Studio itself) for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 ?

A book I bought indicates that option ought to be accessible via "New Project" > Templates > Visual C# > Extensibility. But that option, "Visual Studio Package" is not there.

I did download what's supposedly the VS SDK for 2015 and installed it. It indicated that it is for 2013 as it was installing. And it did not make any difference, even after rebooting.

That SDK, by the way, is quite hard to locate. Microsoft's webpages seem to bounce one around and never give it up. What disorganized crap!

Any tips here would be appreciated. I could revert back to Visual Studio 2013, but I'd rather like to give 2015 a try if this is possible.

Thanks,  James Hurst

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio SDK is now included in Visual Studio Installer and download link is also available inside IDE:

> The Visual Studio Extensibility Tools (VS SDK and templates) are
>   included as an optional feature in Visual Studio setup.
>
> - If you’d like to include the Extensibility Tools with your custom Visual Studio installation, you can find them under Features / Common
>     Tools / Visual Studio Extensibility Tools.
> - You can install the Extensibility Tools at a later time by opening the New Project dialog and selecting the Install Visual Studio
>     Extensibility Tools item under Visual C# / Extensibility.
> - If you open a solution with an extensibility project without first installing the Extensibility Tools, you will be prompted by a
>     highlighted information bar above the Solution Explorer. Click on the
>     Visual Studio Extensibility Tools link to install the Extensibility
>     Tools.

Source:

- [MSDN - Visual Studio SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166441%28v=vs.140%29.aspx)

You might also want to check this must have addon: [Extensibility Tools 2015](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ab39a092-1343-46e2-b0f1-6a3f91155aa6)

Comment: Thank you, Drop. The infor in the link you provided, informed me that "VSIX Package" is actually what I wanted (I guess my book was published prematurely). And I found the "Extensibility Tools 2015". Thank you for your help.